# Cannot return any SharePoint 2013 list or library data via PowerShell - no errors, no data displayed

Tags: 2013, powershell

I want to update some documents metadata (several thousand) in SP2013. Simple do it with a PS script, I'm new to PS but not to programming and there are loads of examples out there - it can't be hard

I have viewed various examples and set out by wanting to step through all the items/documents in a list/folder - no errors, no data. Check a folder I'm looking in exists with `if ($folder.Exists)` and it does, corrupt the name and it does not. Count the number of items and they are zero. Have used the example [here](http://www.robertkuzma.com/2012/09/get-items-from-sharepoint-list-using-powershell-script/) and pointed to my site and list - no output, no error - the list contains data.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are opening "SharePoint Management Shell" and not "Windows PowerShell"

Make sure the account you logged in has enough permission. Also try opening the SharePoint Management Shell by selection `Run as administrator` context menu.

First try below snippet and check you are able to see output on the screen

```
write-host "Starting Script"
$sourceWebURL = "http://sharepointsite"
$sourceListName = "mylist"
$spSourceWeb = Get-SPWeb $sourceWebURL
write-host "Got SPWeb Object"
$spSourceList = $spSourceWeb.Lists[$sourceListName]
write-host "Got SPList"
```

After making the above script working, add following

```
$spSourceItems = $spSourceList.Items
$spSourceItems | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host $_['ID']
    Write-Host $_['Title']
}
```

Now if you want to change the field values. You can do update the loop statements as below

```
$spSourceItems = $spSourceList.Items
$spSourceItems | ForEach-Object {
    $_['Title'] = "New Title"
    $_.Update()
}
```

Comment: Amal, thank you for answering. It was indeed a permission issue.